# AS3 Stage changing by itself, how is it possible?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I'm developing an Air App for Android.
It was going very well when it occurred. Let me explain a bit more: I run the app, everything is ok: the stageWidth is 800 as I've defined before. (I know that is impossible to set stageWidth at runtime and that stageWidth and stageHeight is read only.
I press back/home button and my application loses focus normally, but when I open application again either by recent list apps or menu apps, the stageWidth changes by itself to 1794. I really don't know why this number and not even do not know how is possible alter stageWidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capabilities.screenResolutionX and Capabilities.screenResolutionY are what you should use for screen width and height on apps.  Note: they don't change with rotation - they'll stay the same when screen rotates, so your code will look something like this:

```
if (bStagePortrait) {
    iScreenWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
    iScreenHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
} else {
    iScreenWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
    iScreenHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
}
```

Use this code in app to keep app from stretching and in left corner:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

If you make those changes, you should start seeing good numbers.

Comment: It did work perfectly! I've used Capabilities properties before and It didn't look like as I wanted. But just before, cause now it seems correct. Thank you very much moot.